# PHP Json decode Empty

Tags: php, json, decode

trying to decode a Valid Json string. But failed with PHP:
Online Sandbox:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a7c76cad0116a4ab9621cd1b7d689e34042b8bc8

Cant find any Syntax Error

```
$json='{"before_after":{"name":"before_after","path":".\\(Footage)\\_photos\\photo\\","title":"Before After","slideDesc":"use this Template for Before After Videos","slideNum":12,"snipSets":3,"snipTextMax":8,"snipTextMin":1,"durationslide":{"active":0,"min":20,"max":999,"default":60},"durationsnip":{"active":1,"min":3,"max":12,"default":4},"slideSet":[{"mod":"text","label":"Add Title","label2":"Title"},{"mod":"text","label":"Add Desc","label2":"Desc"},{"mod":"media","label":"Add Teaser","label2":"Teaser"}],"snipSet":[{"mod":"media","text":"Add Pic","label":"Before Media"},{"mod":"media","text":"Add Pic","label":"After Media"},{"mod":"text","text":"Before text","label":"Before Text"},{"mod":"text","text":"After text","label":"After Text"}]},"toplist":{"name":"toplist","path":".\\(Footage)\\_photos\\photo\\","title":"Top Liste","slideDesc":"use this Template for a Top List of Contents","slideNum":12,"snipSets":3,"snipTextMax":8,"snipTextMin":1,"durationslide":{"active":0,"min":20,"max":999,"default":60},"durationsnip":{"active":1,"min":3,"max":12,"default":4},"slideSet":[{"mod":"text","label":"Slide Title","label2":"Title"},{"mod":"text","label":"Slide Description","label2":"Description"},{"mod":"media","label":"Add  Teaser","label2":"Teaser"}],"snipSet":[{"mod":"media","text":"Add Picture","label":"Pic 1"},{"mod":"text","text":"Add text","label":"Picture Text"}]},"timeline":{"name":"timeline","title":"Timeline","path":".\\(Footage)\\_photos\\photo\\","slideDesc":"use this Template for a Timeline","slideNum":12,"snipSets":3,"snipTextMax":8,"snipTextMin":1,"durationslide":{"active":0,"min":20,"max":999,"default":60},"durationsnip":{"active":1,"min":3,"max":12,"default":4},"slideSet":[{"mod":"text","label":"Timeperiod Title","label2":"Title"},{"mod":"text","label":"Slide Description","label2":"Description"},{"mod":"text","label":"Time 2017","label2":"Time 1929","attr":{"type":"number","min":"-4000","max":"2500","required":"required"}},{"mod":"media","label":"Add Teaser","label2":"Teaser"}],"snipSet":[{"mod":"media","text":"Add Picture","label":"Pic 1"},{"mod":"text","text":"Add text","label":"Picture Text"}]}}';
print_r(json_decode($json));//empty
```

Comment: that's because of the double slash, change all instances of \\ to \\\\

Comment: If you look for errors! You will find them!! `$j1 = json_decode($json);
if ( json_last_error() !== 0 ){
    echo json_last_error_msg();
}` Which gives a rather unhelpful `SYNTAX ERROR` but an error none the less

Comment: Thats interesting!!!! The OP marked there own question as a Duplicate. ___Never seen that before___

Comment: @RiggsFolly https://matslew.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/superintelligence-2.jpg